# Big-Theta, Big-O, Big-Omega in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Is the following statement true?

Let $ g : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n $
$$ \Theta_{(g)} = \Omega_{(g)} \cap O_{(g)} $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be an intersection on the right hand side?

Comment: Yes, you are right kodlu. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) $f(n)=O(g(n))$ means that $|f|$ is bounded above by $g$ asymptotically. Formally,
$$
\exists k>0\quad\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n>n_0:\quad|f(n)|\leq k\cdot g(n).
$$
Note that this implies that $f$ is also bounded above by $g$ asymptotically.

The [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ means that $f$ is bounded below by $g$ asymptotically.
Formally,
$$
\exists k>0\quad\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N},n>n_0:\quad f(n)\geq k\cdot g(n).
$$
The [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ means that $f$ is bounded both above and below by $g$ asymptotically. Formally,
$$
\exists k_1>0\quad\exists k_2>0\quad\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n>n_{0}:\quad k_1\cdot g(n)\leq f(n)\leq k_2\cdot g(n).
$$
Note that if $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, then both $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ hold, which means that

> $$
> \Theta(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \cap \Omega(g(n)),
> $$

by definition.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer @user153012.